# page source extraction is not complete

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, automation

I am trying to scrape a specific website and attempting to get the page source only returns partial html.

Executing the sample code only returns the top side of the page as html. I have tried to scroll the page -> if I do so and scroll the page to the bottom, I get only the bottom side of the page and the top side is missing.
I am expecting to get the complete page source from top to bottom. Thanks in advance!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import time

url = 'https://sharky.fi/lend'
user_agent = UserAgent().random
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install(), options=options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(15)
browser_source = driver.page_source
driver.close()
print(browser_source)
```

Comment: Elements are populated within the DOM through _Lazy Loading_

Comment: Some sites will only load a certain portion of the content at a time.  When you scroll it doesn't necessarily only append, but shows a certain buffer amount of content... this avoids overloading the browser with too much content which can slow down scripts and such...

Comment: Some sites are just set up like that. You can't get all the data at once - you'll have to get it in batches